# managing Azure file storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have an Azure file storage to support one of our applications which runs daily.  We know have a long list of files dated November, December, and month-to-date January.

I want to create 2017_November and 2017_December sub-directories and then move the relevant files into those directories. I don't believe this can be accomplished through the portal.  Can anyone help me with how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this (or at least most intuitive) is connect the file storage as file share and open up explorer and do those things.

This should help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows